# Android: Handling Activity stack

Tags: android

I've got the following:

Activities `A, B, C, D`. `A` and `D` can be reached at any time, anywhere from the application.

`B` and `C` are reached like this:

```
A -> B -> C
```

I have the following use case:

The user has entered `C` ( `A -> B -> C` ) then she has gone to `D`.

When she wants to go to `A`, I want to transfer her to the already started queue from `A` - in other words I want her to go to the started `C`.

Something like this `A -> B -> C -> D -> (same) C`. But I don't want to lose `D` from the activity stack. After this, when she presses the "back" button, she is transfered to `D` again.

Is this possible and correct to do? What is the best practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do this.  [The documentation says the following](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#lmodes):

> Note that when a new instance of an Activity is created to handle a new intent, the user can always press the BACK key to return to the previous state (to the previous activity). But **when an existing instance of an Activity handles a new intent, the user cannot press the BACK key to return to what that instance was doing before the new intent arrived**.

Basically you can't have the same instance of Activity C in two places in the stack at the same time.

However, you could make it appear that this was the case by making Activity C save its transient state to the [`Application` object](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/app/Application.html) for your application.  This would allow all instances of Activity C to share state and so appear as if they were the same instance.

You'd need to create your own subclass of `Application` and then read and write to it from Activity C in `onResume()` and `onPause()`.

Comment: actually, just posting this from another answer, there is a way to do this:

"You can try this FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT (the document describes exactly what you want to)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT"

Comment: @Danail - That doesn't quite do what you wanted.  It will change the order to `A -> B -> D -> C` which means pressing back from Activity D will take the user to `B`.  (I think so from reading the documentation anyway, I haven't tried it.)

Comment: absolutely right! But still, it saves me from creating a LOT of unnecessary objects, and I think it can help people landing on this question.